# Определить кол-во дней между датами

Tags: php

Задана некая дата в формате timestamp, например 1581624000,
нужно понять сколько дней осталось до этой даты.

Какие есть варианты ?

Comment: Вычесть текущую дату в том же виде и поделить на 86400 (кол-во секунд в сутках)

Comment: @Mike  
так? ($time - time()) / 86400 ?

Comment: приведите свои варианты(кода), раз уж вы знаете задание, явно пытались что либо сделать

Comment: @3214234 Ага, только убедитесь что получилось число > 0 (дата еще не наступила) и возможно округлите до целых, если надо только дни

Comment: @finally А какой вы интересно ожидаете код от ТС ? Я не думаю, что можно написать хоть строку, не зная, что за число такое 1581624000 и с чем его едят. Вопрос в общем то абсолютно корректен

Comment: `echo (new DateTime(date('d.m.Y', 1581624000)))->diff((new DateTime(date('d.m.Y', time()))))->format('%d');`